# htaccess allow from 127.0.0.1 not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using XAMPP on windows 7. I put this htaccess file in my `htdocs` folder and I'm getting access denied when I try to open `http://localhost/`.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Deny from all
```

I want to deny access to any computers other than this one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precedence is everything!

If you allow localhost to connect, and afterwards deny ALL ips, the deny overwrites the allow.

So you'd first apply the blacklist (deny all) and then the whitelist (allow localhost).

```
Order deny,allow # <--- order to apply the white/blacklist change
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Deny from all
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

> The Order directive goes hand-in-hand with these two, and tells Apache
>   in which order to apply the filters.

Comment: For information, since Apache 2.4, it simply becomes `Require local`

Comment: Thank you for this.  The ::1 on a seperate line was the key.  I have been working on this for hours and your solution works.  Again - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that this works too:

`Order deny,allow
    Allow from ::1
    Deny from all`

I did not have to have the 

    `Allow from 127.0.0.1`

What is ::1 mean please?

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 representation of `127.0.0.1`.